# Connect to php websocket server with xamarin android

Tags: xamarin, websocket, xamarin.android, phpwebsocket

I'm trying to use websockets in Xamarin. I already have a websocket server written in php and I want to connect to it with an Android client app using Xamarin. 
Is it possible do that? Or can I just connect to .NET servers?

Thank you so much!!

Comment: Not sure, but is this maybe be helpful to you? https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/27729/how-to-implement-a-websocket-server-using-c-for-a-android-app-xamarin .

Comment: @JordyDieltjens thank you for your answer! But from what I understand is always related to .NET. I'm trying to know if is possible to use something like a library or else to connect to php websocket server using c# android app! But I'm not sure if is possible with xamarin or not...

Comment: I know there is a package (= library) for websockets in xamarin pcl (=crossplatform) . But since you are working only in android I don't think you can use it. (this is the library i'm talking about: https://github.com/NVentimiglia/WebSockets.Pcl ). Good luck and I hope someone can help you

Comment: @jordy Ok thank you so much! So I give a look at that!

Comment: @JordyDieltjens I did the app in crossplatform way and I used the packages you told me! It works great!! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Glad to hear that :). Have a nice one!